# WYSIWIG Editor that exports plain HTML

Tags: html, lyx

I have a need for a WYSIWIG editor that exports plain HTML with no styles, divs, classes, or any such other markup. Basically I want to be able to create simple documents with structure, export to HTML and then upload to a CMS. The CMS controls the style, so all I need are the bare HTML tags.

I know I could do this in a text editor, but I'm not fond of typing in tags by hand, and I also benefit from a good spell checker.

I have looked for a way to write in LyX and then export to HTML from there, but the exported file includes some style information, which gets in my way on the CMS side.

I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks for any hints!

Josh

Comment: Markup is a key feature of HTML (it's right there in the name). "*[P]lain HTML with no...markup*" is simply unformatted text. It's not clear if you seek a limited set of tags, or some different kind of markup.

Comment: That's fine with me if you want to close it. The question was looking for advice on an editor that would save HTML files with no extra style information--just structure. I figured I'd ask on this forum since I use Ubuntu and non-Ubuntu editors wouldn't be of much use to me. Apologies if this is not the forum for such a question.

Comment: It's not quite what you're after, but it's easy to use and has buttons for anything you're gonna need. It's not quite WYSIWYG, but it's really easy. http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html (I've recently been searching for mostly the same thing and that's what I came up with as the tool that works best for me.)

Answer (score 1):

I see what you mean. I guess what I am looking for is the plain markup with no other style information. Just the tags, as it were.

I think I found a solution that works for me: Seamonkey! The basic editor let's me save to HTML with nothing but the markup.